# Error: 'array': ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, boost

I'm tring to use boost array

but I got this error:

> error: 'array': ambiguous symbol

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace boost;

using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    array<int, 10> a{3};

    cout << "a[0]= " << a[0];

    return 0;
}
```

This error arise when I include the boost library

any idea ?

Comment: `array` was accepted into `std`. Why are you still trying to use the old `boost` version? And here is the peril of `using namespace`: now you have both versions floating around in the (conceptual) global symbol space. I believe this applies to `regex`, too. Just use the `std` versions, preferably fully qualified (no `using namespace`).

Comment: I'm learning the boost library

Comment: So stop `using namespace` when you're just inviting conflicts with the parts of said library that were accepted into `std`. Because then you have to disambiguate by prefixing with `boost::` or `std::`... which you can and should do without ever typing `using namespace` anyway.

Comment: so I have to remove `using namespace std;
` ?

Comment: There are various ways to do this, but in my opinion (and I believe that of many others), the best is to avoid `using namespace` and just qualify all symbols with their full namespace: `std::array` or `boost::array`

Comment: You should remove `using namespace std;` **and** `using namespace boost;`.

Comment: I'm curious though, by not having `#include <array>` I would've thought this wouldn't be a problem in this case. But anyway, indeed you should not have the `using namespace` statements for reasons already given above.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury I guess it's included via `<iostream>` or one of its (probably many and interwoven) dependencies. With header files, anything is possible (though most of it is bad!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`boost::array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/array.html) and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) are not ambiguous because they are scoped by different namespaces.

When you do:

```
using namespace boost;
using namespace std;
```

You tell the compiler to look symbols up in both these namespaces. But the compiler now doesn't know which `array` you're talking about when you just type `array`. It could be `boost::array` or it could be `std::array` thus it is ambiguous.

**You could fix this by either removing the `using namespace std;` or by specifying that you're using the Boost version by using `boost::array` instead of just `array`.**

---

Incidentally I understand trying to learn Boost functionality, but you shouldn't bother learning `boost::array`, right in [the Introduction to `boost::array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/array.html#array.intro) it tells you:

> `std::array` is (as of C++11) part of the C++ standard. The differences between `boost::array` and `std::array` are minimal. If you are using C++11, you should consider using `std::array` instead of `boost::array`.

Answer (score 0):

add core:: before the array
so core::array

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you please elaborate on this answer and why it is different from the previous answer? Thanks

Comment: Previous one did not work for me so i added this to it